# Using Java, I need to split a string into sections into an arrayList between 2 capital letters

Tags: java, string

I need to split a string into substrings and record the results in an `ArrayList`.  Substrings will be delimited by pairs of capital letters, with each pair *included* in the preceding substring.  For example, if the string was:

`String testString = "Linda Dumas 3393 Pennsylvania Avenue Portland TX Huazhang Hanlon 3428 Main Road Miami NH ";`

The output would be `{"Linda Dumas 3393 Pennsylvania Avenue Portland TX", "Huazhang Hanlon 3428 Main Road Miami NH"}`

The actual input string has about 200 addresses. I’ve tried using regular expressions to do this, but I just get the return of the two capital letters. I was thinking you would use this in a substring method but kept getting too many errors doing that. Any help is appreciated.

This is what I had before I started receiving errors (yes I know there is a problem with the testString.charAt(q+2) and q+1):

```
String testString = "Linda Dumas 3393 Pennsylvania Avenue Portland TX Huazhang Hanlon 3428 Main Road Miami NH ";
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{2}").matcher(testString);
for (int q = 0; q < testString.length() - 1; q++){
    if (Character.isUpperCase(testString.charAt(q))
            && Character.isUpperCase(testString.charAt(q + 1))){
        address = new StringBuilder().append(testString.charAt(q)).append(testString.charAt(q+2)).toString();
        list.add(address);
    }
}
// System.out.println(list);
while (m.find()) {
    allMatches.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(allMatches);
```

Comment: Is all input on the same line? Or multiple lines?

Comment: one line, the actual string I am using was converted so it would be on one line as well

Comment: If these string are input from end users you need some validation of the things the type. If someone writes their name as BO HO the logic will break.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestAddress {

  private static final String testString = "Linda Dumas 3393 Pennsylvania Avenue Portland TX Huazhang Hanlon 3428 Main Road Miami NH foo bar FB";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Set fromIndex to the start of the string
    int fromIndex = 0;
    // Go through the input string one char at a time
    for(int i = 0; i < testString.length()-1; i++) {
      // If the current char (i) and the next char (i+1) are both uppercase...
      if(Character.isUpperCase(testString.charAt(i)) && Character.isUpperCase(testString.charAt(i+1))) {
        // ...Copy the substring from fromIndex to i+2 into the list
        addresses.add(testString.substring(fromIndex, i+2));
        // ...And set fromIndex to just after the pair of uppercase letters
        fromIndex = i+3;
      }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(i + ": " + addresses.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this is probably really stupid but I'm getting this error on the List<String> addresses = .....

Comment: The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Comment: Explaining the pieces of logic/code would also be quite helpful.

Comment: @RyanG23, you are probably importing `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the text leading up to the double capital in your pattern, or else inquire of the `Matcher` about details of the match.  The former is easier:

```
String testString = "Linda Dumas 3393 Pennsylvania Avenue Portland TX Huazhang Hanlon 3428 Main Road Miami NH ";
Pattern addressPattern = Pattern.compile(".*?[A-Z]{2}");
Matcher m = addressPattern.matcher(testString);
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();

while (m.find()) {
    allMatches.add(m.group().trim());
}

System.out.println(allMatches);
```

Note that that regex pattern uses a "reluctant quantifier" (`*?`) to avoid slurping up multiple addresses into one match.  A reluctant quantifier matches only the minimum number of characters needed to make the overall match succeed.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
String testString = "Linda Dumas 3393 Pennsylvania Avenue Portland TX Huazhang Hanlon 3428 Main Road Miami NH";

List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(testString.split("(?<=[A-Z]{2})")));
```

Comment: Nice.  I'd upvote it twice if I could, at least if it went the whole nine yards and got the result into `ArrayList` form.

Comment: what is the longStringWithAddresses supposed to be, gives me an error of not knowing what this is; wants me to create a variable for it.

Comment: It'd be the test string containing all the addresses - just renamed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you aren't appending to the string as you go, you are only appending when your condition is met. Try something alone these lines... I don't know how the address class is arranged, but you can alter this to work, I'm sure.

```
String testString = "Linda Dumas 3393 Pennsylvania Avenue Portland TX Huazhang Hanlon 3428 Main Road Miami NH ";
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{2}").matcher(testString);

for (int q = 0; q < testString.length() - 1; q++){
    if (Character.isUpperCase(testString.charAt(q)) && Character.isUpperCase(testString.charAt(q + 1))){
                list.add(str);
     }

      // Keep appending until we reach our 2 capital letters
      str.append(testString.charAt(q));
}
// System.out.println(list);
while (m.find()) {
    allMatches.add(m.group());
    }
        System.out.println(allMatches);
}
```